# I can't connect between pages in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm a newbie about windows phone, this is my first project, a app calculate calories when running in wp8.1 RT, but I have a problem, basically I have 3 pages, mainpage is page 1, how must I do whenever I click a button in page 1 (start running), a stopwatch in page 3 starts counting and start receiving data gps of Map in page 2 (distance,speed) automatically, ie I'm still in page 1, the other pages run in background if i don't navigate to them ? ( I implemented stopwatch and map in project), forgive me because I'm not good at English.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows Phone App (does not matter if is silverlight or RT) you just can run a page at time.

Instead use several pages, you can use [Background task](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) or [Geofencing](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66).

I hope it helps you.